# File upload using ajax and rest web service

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, rest

I am using ajax and rest web service to upload files to the server. I have captured the file upload event and got the file object in my jquery method. I have to send the file object to web service so that i can save the file to db.
Here is my jquery code..

```
  $scope.selectFile = function (fileObj) {
     if(fileObj!=undefined){
        $.ajax({
            url : "/RestServices/services/uploadFile",
            type : "POST",
            data : fileObj,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success : function(result) {
                $scope.$apply();
            },
            error : function(xhr, tStatus, err) {
                // alert(err);
            }
        });
     }
```

I have tried using FormData also, but I couldn't get the file in web service.

```
    var formData = new FormData(); 
    formData.append("fileToUpload", fileObj);   

     if(fileObj!=undefined){
        $.ajax({
            url : "/RestServices/services/uploadFile",
            type : "POST",
            data : formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success : function(result) {
                $scope.$apply();
            },
            error : function(xhr, tStatus, err) {
                // alert(err);
            }

        });
```

Here is my java code in service

```
@POST
@Path("/uploadFile")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public void uploadFile(File formData) {     
try {
        System.out.println(formData.getFileName());             
   } catch (Exception e) {
    LOGGER.error("Exception in Upload File Endpoint"+ e.getMessage());
}   
}
```

If I send file Object directly without using formData, i am getting "media type not supported error" and if i send formData to service, i am getting temporary file only.
What datatype should be there in ajax and in service methods? How can I get the uploaded file in the service? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I stepped upon this problem today, and I solved it like this:

**HTML**

```
 <input type="button" value="Upload document" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary uploadDocumentOnboarding">
 <input id="file" type="file" class="findDocumentOnboarding">
```

**Ajax/Jquery**

```
$(".uploadDocumentGeneral").on("click", function (evt) {

var documentData = new FormData();
documentData.append('file', $('input#file.findDocumentOnboarding')[0].files[0]);
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: documentData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (response) {
        alert("Document uploaded successfully.");
    }
});

return false;
```

});

**JAVA**

```
@POST
@Path("upload/{id}")
@Consumes({"application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "multipart/form-data"})

public void addBlob(@PathParam("id") Integer id, @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream) throws IOException {
    E24ClientTemp entityToMerge = find(id);
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        entityToMerge.setTestBlob(out.toByteArray());
        super.edit(entityToMerge);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I know it's a little late but I saw the question didn't have an answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

The method of uploading a file is really different than just an ajax request. Additionally, it is really hard to consider all the old browsers. Fortunately, other people have solved this problem for us.

I recommend using a plugin for jQuery like [jQuery File Upload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/), or use [Dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/), which is totally awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I have it working this way:

```
//JAVASCRIPT

    var objFile = $jQuery("#fileToUpload");
    var file = objFile[0].files[0];
    API.call({
        url : "rest-url/upload",
        type : "POST",
        contentType : "multipart/form-data",
        data: file,
        processData: false
    }); 

//JAVA

@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("rest-url/upload")
public Response upload(InputStream fileInputStream) throws Exception {
    //here you got your file
    return Response.ok().entity(new Object("response")).build();
}
```